# Scrollview with multiple cards

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

I am trying to put three cards in Scrollview, and the cards should all be different. Also, below all of the cards, I would like to put a button. How can I do that? Since I am new to Android, I don't even know if this is the right approach? Here's my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/choose_massage"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/login_arrow"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/massageViewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Ultimately, I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: @jively see my answer below.

Comment: you want scrolling horizontally or vertically?

Comment: Verically, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: then why using viewpager? better to use recyclerview

Comment: and where is multiple cards? you have only one

Comment: The viewpager is withing the cardview and so far it is working, so I don't want to touch that. I tried adding more cardviews and it works fine, but I can't seem to add a button on the bottom which wouldn't be in a card view. Or should i make that button take up the whole space of the card view and put no borders on the cardview so it looks like a normal button?

Comment: you need to add button at bottom and and want to scroll page?

Comment: @AdityaVyas I've updated my question with an image, please check it out.

Comment: do you want three cardview with scrolview ? or anything else ?

Comment: I don't know yet, most likely 2-3 cardviews with a scrollview and a button on the very bottom (which would not be in a cardview).

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this way this worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollablContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="asdfasdf"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="asdfasdf"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/batss"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerView"
        android:orientation="vertical"


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Footer"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This way I can scroll the cardviews, but the button on the bottom (which is not in a cardview) is always shown. What I need is that the user sees the cardviews, scrolls down and then he/she sees the button.

Comment: i dont understand what you need

Comment: Basically, I needed everything to be scrollable along with the button on the bottom, which will be shown only when you scroll to the end. Sorry, maybe I didn't know how to explain.

Comment: then simply put button at last in xml

Answer (score 0):

check this one;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/nameCardView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dip" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="3" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2.6"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Name"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="First"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details4"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />
                    </LinearLayout >
                </LinearLayout >
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dip" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/product"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/_Details"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.75"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:hint="Second"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />
                    </LinearLayout >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gift"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/__Details"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.75"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:hint="cardview"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details11"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details12"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details14"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details15"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Details16"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="cardview"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                            android:textStyle="normal" />
                    </LinearLayout >
                </LinearLayout >
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearScrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dip" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/Details21"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                                android:hint="Third"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/darkslate"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                                android:hint="cardview"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/darkslate"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/Details23"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="cardview"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/Details22"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="end"
                                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="cardview"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                                android:textStyle="normal" />
                        </LinearLayout >
                    </LinearLayout >
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView >
            </LinearLayout >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:hint="click"
                android:padding="5dip" />
        </LinearLayout >
    </ScrollView >
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I do it like this, the button is always shown.

Comment: Button will be allways shown in above posted code. It is out of scroolview

Comment: Yes, but I needed it to be shown only when you scroll on the bottom.

Comment: Yes, I already solved it yesterday, I even put my solution as an answer. I've manage to do it slightly different than you did. Thank you for your effort! Best, jay

Answer (score 0):

Use a list view instead i.e a custom list view! With a card view in it as a layout